# How to fake the object initiation using FakeItEasy?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, fakeiteasy

Following is the code for which I want to write unit tests:

```
public virtual ActionResult TryIt()
{
    MemberViewModel viewModel = new MemberViewModel();

    _memberViewModelLookupBuilder.PopulateSelectLists(viewModel);

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

I want to write unit tests to fake the MemberViewModel object so that I can write tests for rest of the operations in action.
Something like -

```
A.CallTo(() => viewModel = new TryItViewModel()).Returns(viewModel);
```

But this doesn't work and gives an error saying

> "An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator"

Can anyone please advice how I can achieve this?

I am using xUnit and FakeItEasy in my test project.

Any help on this much appreciated.

Comment: XClass xClass = FakeItEasy.Sdk.Create.Fake(SubXClass) as XClass ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FakeItEasy cannot impose arbitrary behaviour on concrete methods, for example class constructors. You have to start with a fake and configure it.

This can be accomplished by injecting a fake `MemberViewModel` into the `TryIt` method. The typical route would be to extract an interface from `MemberViewModel` (or even better, rely on an existing one), fake it, and pass it to `TryIt`. So `TryIt` becomes:

```
public virtual ActionResult TryIt(IMemberViewModel viewModel)
{
     _memberViewModelLookupBuilder.PopulateSelectLists(viewModel);
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

And in your production code you would pass in a `new MemberViewModel`. The tests would then fake out the object:

```
var fakeMemberViewModel = A.Fake<IMemberViewModel>();
A.CallTo(() => fakeMemberViewModel.SomeMethod()).Returns(17);

TryIt(fakeMemberViewModel);

…
```

For another example, see the [FakeItEasy Quickstart](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart/).

Comment: I think Mock framework is providing the ability to fake the class constructors using "Setup" methods, if I am not wrong. Not sure, if the provided solution going to work in larger scale projects. I mean, there shouldn't be an easy task to create Interfaces for each and every ViewModel. I believe FakeItEasy should have some mechanism to allow this.

Comment: @Nirman, I don't understand all of your comments: 

"I think Mock framework is providing the ability to fake the class constructors using "Setup" methods,"

Aside from that, I see the suggested approach work every day in quite a large enterprise software system.

That being said, I understand it's not all that convenient. Due to the platform FakeItEasy is built on, faking constructors is not feasible.

However, other mocking frameworks, such as [Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page) and [JustMock](http://www.telerik.com/products/mocking.aspx) do support mocking constructors.